# Determine number of grouped values within a grid

Tags: java, grid, logic, grouping, cell

Was wondering if anyone could help me with some logic.

Say I have a grid that consists of:

```
  1 2 3
1 A B A
2 A B B
3 A A B
```

There are 3 groups in this grid, which are determined by each cell's value and all the neighboring cells which have the same value, so assuming coordinate scheme is (col, row):

Group 1: (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3) which has a value of A

Group 2: (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3) which has a value of B

Group 3: (3, 1) which has a value of A

Could anyone suggest how would I determine this programmatically?

I was thinking along the lines of:

- Use a for loop to iterate through the grid

  - Have a method which checks the cell's top, right, bottom and left cell's value (also accounting for the boundary cells)

    - Check if the cell is of the same value, then store it somehow
    - Otherwise it is a new group?
  - Recurse

But I can't get around what to do if it finds a cell with a different value. I think I'm over complicating a simple solution here.

I would ideally like to store an array of coordinates which relate to all the groups within the grid.

Comment: Wouldn't group 1 have the value ABAB? (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3) have the values A, B, A, B. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the coordinate scheme is (col, row). So the first group is all the A's on the left of the grid and the bottom middle one.

I'm trying to determine firstly, how many different groups there are in the grid, and then get the coordinates of each cell it belongs to. Hope this has made is more clear

Comment: Okay, I think I kind of got it. So you want an array of coordinates for each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the conceptually easiest way to handle this is with recursion. Granted, because of Java's subpar tail-recursion support, an iterative solution would be more efficient; still, recursion should work for smallish values.

Take a look at this sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int xBound = 3;
    int yBound = 3;
    String[][] grid = new String[][] {
        {"A", "B", "A"},
        {"A", "B", "B"},
        {"A", "A", "B"} 
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < yBound; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < xBound; j++) {
            String state = grid[i][j];
            List<List<Integer>> group = getGroup(state, j, i, xBound, yBound, grid);
            if (group.size() != 0) {
                System.out.println(state + " " + group);
            }   
        }
    }
}

static List<List<Integer>> getGroup(String state, int xIndex, int yIndex, int xBound, int yBound, String[][] grid) {
    if (xIndex >= xBound || xIndex < 0 || yIndex >= yBound || yIndex < 0 || grid[yIndex][xIndex].equals("USED")) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    } else if (grid[yIndex][xIndex].equals(state)){
        grid[yIndex][xIndex] = "USED";

        List<List<Integer>> ourPosse = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        ourPosse.add(Arrays.asList(yIndex, xIndex));
        ourPosse.addAll(getGroup(state, xIndex + 1, yIndex, xBound, yBound, grid));
        ourPosse.addAll(getGroup(state, xIndex - 1, yIndex, xBound, yBound, grid));
        ourPosse.addAll(getGroup(state, xIndex, yIndex + 1, xBound, yBound, grid));
        ourPosse.addAll(getGroup(state, xIndex, yIndex - 1, xBound, yBound, grid));

        return ourPosse;
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

We step through the grid, trying to use each entry as the "root" of a new group. If a distinct group is in fact rooted at that entry (i.e. grpCt != 0), then we print it.

In the getGroupMethod, we first check whether we've gone out of our grid bounds or whether we've already used entry in a previous group. Note that this checking is done by mutating the grid, but we could keep a memo instead.

Otherwise, if the present entry matches the state we're looking to group on, then we add this entry to the group and then expand in all directions, looking for other entries to add to the group.

Otherwise, we know the present entry can't be part of the group.

Edit: In terms of asymptotic running time, because we're effectively memoizing by setting the flag in the grid and thus only considering each entry at most 4 times, we've got O(n^2).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! The "USED" flag was the thing I couldn't get my head around.

However, as you said I just now need to rewrite the getGroup method  to return the x and y coordinates for each group.

Comment: I had just finished writing something similar, but you've solved it! Thanks a lot